# Whats the derivative of $\sqrt{4+|x|}$ using first principle

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here is my attempt:

$$f(x)=\sqrt{4+|x|}$$
$$f`(x) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{4+|x-h|}-\sqrt{4+|x|}}{h}$$
multiplying by the conjugate:
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{4+|x-h|-4-|x|}{h[\sqrt{4+|x-h|}+\sqrt{4+|x|}]}$$
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{|x-h|-|x|}{h[\sqrt{4+|x-h|}+\sqrt{4+|x|}]}$$

What is the next step? how can I deal with absloute value of |x|?

Comment: My gut is telling me to look at left and right handed limits but I haven't done all the computations yet so I'm unsure if this will give you the answer.

Comment: Split the domain of the function into $x \gt 0$ ($f(x)=\sqrt{4+x}$)   and $x \le 0$ ($f(x)=\sqrt{4-x}$). Both halves are easily differentiable, then show they have the same value at $x=0$

Comment: It would be easier to deal with two cases: $x$ non-negative and $x$ negative. When you get a formula for each you can combine them using the absolute value and signum ($+1$ for positive, $-1$ for negative) functions. (That is, if you want to end up with a single formula.) Show these are equal at $x=0$.

Comment: @TomCollinge Not sure, but I guess that $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: @Thekwasti: I think you are correct. $f_-'(0) = -1/4$ whereas $f_+'(0) = +1/4$, so $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of the function looks like this: it isn't differentiable at x = 0.

As noted in the comments, Split the domain of the function into

x>0 $f(x)=\sqrt{4+x}$ and

x≤0 f(x)= $\sqrt{4-x}$.

Both halves are easily differentiable, but have different values at x = 0 (or to be more precise, the limiting value for x > 0 differs from the value for x = 0).

[image]

(P.S - this is quite an interesting web site: http://fooplot.com/

Answer (score 1):

First note that if $f(x)=\sqrt{4+|x|}$, then
$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(0) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{4+|0+h|}-\sqrt{4+|0|}}{h}= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sqrt{4+|h|}-\sqrt{4}}{h}
$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}-\sqrt{4}\right)\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}+\sqrt{4}\right)}{h\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}+\sqrt{4}\right)}
$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{4+|h|-4}{h\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}+2\right)}= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{|h|}{h\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}+2\right)} $$
From the left of zero, we have
$$
\lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{|h|}{h\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}+2\right)}= \lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{-h}{h\left(\sqrt{4-h}+2\right)}
$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{-1}{\left(\sqrt{4-h}+2\right)}=-\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{4}+2\right)}=-\frac14
$$
From the right of zero, we have
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{|h|}{h\left(\sqrt{4+|h|}+2\right)}= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{h}{h\left(\sqrt{4+h}+2\right)}
$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{4+h}+2\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{4}+2\right)}=\frac14
$$
Therefore, $f(x)$ is **not** differentiable at $x=0$.